# How can I render a form inside of a modal thats located in a different controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I put this **<%= render "softruns/form"%>** inside a modal that is located in the home\index.html.erb file. The **form** is located in the "Softrun" controller under the softruns\form.html.erb .......  I am getting this error

**First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**

and it is pointing at this line of code that is at the top of the softruns_form.html.erb file

**<%= form_for @softrun, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>**

Are there any route, or controller modifications that need to be done with this?

home\index.html.erb file

```
<div class ="row">
<div class="span10">
    <div class="well"> 
        <h2>Hello Traders, </h2>
        <p class="lead"> There will be text here</p> 

        <h3>Our Thinking is .......</h3>
        <p class="lead">There will be text here</p>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large  btn-info" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>Keep Me Posted</a>

    </div>
   </div>
</div>

   
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">We're shooting for a Nov 10 '14 launch</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 style="text-align:center"><a href="mailto:info@tradertwitch.com"> Info@TraderTwitch.com</a></h3> 

        <h4 style="text-align:center">Email us to stay in the loop. </h4> 

                
        <hr>
        <div><%= render "softruns/form"%></div>
     
            <p><small class="text-muted">*We will not give out your email or twitter handle.</small></p>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>
```

softruns\form.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for @softrun, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :soft_email, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :soft_email, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :soft_twitter, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :soft_twitter, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :prim_session, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :prim_session, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                softruns_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

  def traderoom
  end

  def testimonials
  end

  def bio
  end
end
```

softruns_controller.rb

```
class SoftrunsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_softrun, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /softruns
  # GET /softruns.json
  def index
    @softruns = Softrun.all
  end

  # GET /softruns/1
  # GET /softruns/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /softruns/new
  def new
    @softrun = Softrun.new
  end

  # GET /softruns/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /softruns
  # POST /softruns.json
  def create
    @softrun = Softrun.new(softrun_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @softrun.save
        format.html { redirect_to @softrun, notice: 'Softrun was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @softrun }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @softrun.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /softruns/1
  # PATCH/PUT /softruns/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @softrun.update(softrun_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @softrun, notice: 'Softrun was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @softrun.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /softruns/1
  # DELETE /softruns/1.json
  def destroy
    @softrun.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to softruns_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_softrun
      @softrun = Softrun.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def softrun_params
      params.require(:softrun).permit(:soft_email, :soft_twitter, :prim_session)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Tradertwitch::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :softruns

  get "home/index"
  get "home/about"
  get "home/contact"
  get "home/traderoom"
  get "home/testimonials"
  get "home/bio"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: Looks like you're only missing declaration of `@softrun` in your `HomeController#index`.  Define it as `@softrun = Softrun.new` in your HomeController's index action and that should fix the error.

Comment: How can i give you points for helping me ? i do not see a button

Comment: you're welcome.  The issue was very specific so I used comment to answer.  No worries on the points, please feel free to delete the question if you like.

Comment: I use all my past questions for my own references too...ha....I hope it doesn't affect my SO status.